# Refreshing specific - multiple owl carousel on click handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have more owl carousels of the same class. But is a problem how to target the current slider and on click refresh next one, who will be current.

My handler:

```
$(".office-gallery").each(function (obj, index) {
   $(this).owlCarousel({...});
});


$("button").on("click", function () {
  targetCurrentOrSpecifficIndexSlider.trigger("refresh.owl.carousel"); // or .trigger("to.owl.carousel", [0, 1, true]);
});
```

I have tried to set the variable:

```
let outTarget = null;
$(".office-gallery").each(function (obj, index) {
   outTarget = $(this).owlCarousel({...});
});
...
outTarget[0(or index)].trigger("refresh.owl.carousel"); // or .trigger("to.owl.carousel", [0, 1, true]);
```

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: you can add container like div for each carousels then on click the button and carousel must be in the same "div" container then use jquery to get the element using .closest("div.ClassName") then use .find(".CarouselClasss") to update

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***closest()*** and ***find()*** functions by jquery to resolve it:

**(Add container for carousel and the button)**

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
      $(this).closest(".CarouselContainer").find(".office-gallery").trigger("refresh.owl.carousel");
    });
```